# Ativar o hover em serie

Tags: jquery

Pessoal tenho a seguinte estrutura:

```
<h2>
        <a class="imgHover" title="titulo" href="#">
            <span id="box" class="imgHover">
                <img src="imagens/estrutura.jpg" width="400" height="260" 
            alt="titulo" />
                <span class="titulo">Titulo da imagem</span>
            </span>
        </a>
    </h2>
```

Eu uso o seguinte Jquery no Hover para alterar a opacidade.

```
$(document).ready(function ($) {
    var navDuration = 150;
    $('.imgHover').hover(function () {
        //$(this).children("span").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, navDuration);
        $(this).children("img").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, navDuration);
    }, function () {
        //$(this).children("span").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, navDuration*2);
        $(this).children("img").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, navDuration * 2);
    });
});
```

Assim funciona legal, so que eu preciso também alterar a opacidade do SPAN. Ai quando eu descomento as linhas que tem o SPAN no script o mesmo não funciona mais perfeitamente.
O que esta de errado? Obrigado

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## 1º Localizar elemento correto

Assumindo que o elemento responsável pela animação é o `<a/>`, o teu problema está na maneira como apanhas o elemento `<span/>`, porque como tens dois elementos  dentro do elemento `.imgHover`, vai estar a animar a opacidade de ambos.

Isto complica-se mais porque uma `<span/>` está dentro da outra, e a `<img/>` também dentro de uma `<span/>` o que gera uma enorme confusão de animações de opacidades.

### Solução

Dependendo do que pretendes, deverás alterar a maneira como localizas a `<span/>`:

- Se pretendes a que se encontra ao lado da imagem:

  ```
  $(this).find('span > span')
  ```
- Se pretendes a que está a envolver a imagem:

  ```
  $(this).find('> span')
  ```

### Exemplo

Assumindo que pretendes animar a imagem e o elemento ao seu lado, o teu código ficaria:

```
var navDuration = 150;
$('.imgHover').hover(function() {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.find('span > span').stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, navDuration);
    $this.find("img").stop().animate({ opacity: 0.6 }, navDuration);

  }, function () {

    var $this = $(this);

    $this.find('span > span').stop().animate({ opacity: 0.5 }, navDuration*2);
    $this.find("img").stop().animate({ opacity: 1 }, navDuration*2);
  });
```

---

## 2º Elemento que deverá despoletar a animação

Outra coisa é o fato de teres dois elementos com a classe `.imgHover`, um dentro do outro. Isto faz como que a animação ocorra duas vezes, concorrencialmente.

### Solução

Se pretendes que a animação seja despoletada pelo elemento `<a/>`, deverás:

```
$('a.imgHover').hover(function() { ...
```

Se pretendes que a animação seja despoletada pelo elemento `<span/>`, podes:

```
$('span.imgHover').hover(function() { ...
```

Ou como tens um ID neste último elemento:

```
$('#box').hover(function() { ...
```

Comment: Obrigado. Deu certinho.

Answer (score 0):

Você não pode fazer em css selecionando o elemento diretamente.

```
imgHover:hover img {
      0% display:none ; opacity: 0;
      1% display: block ; opacity: 0;
      100% display: block ; opacity: 1;
    }
```

Comment: O que é estas porcentagens sem propriedade?